# Is it more efficient to create multiple tables for different users?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-performance

The title isn't very specific, so I'll elaborate.

I'm working on a database system in which users can add data to a **postgres** database though a watered-down API.

So far, all the user's data is compiled into one table, structured similar this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE UserData (
    userId int NOT NULL,
    dataId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    key varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    data json not NOT NULL,
);
```

However, I am thinking that it may be more efficient (and a faster query) to instead give each userId it's own table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE UserData_{userId} (
    dataId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    key varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    data json not NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE UserData_{anotherUserId} ();
etc...
```

I am worried that this will clog up the database, however.

What are the pros and cons for each? Under what load/speed requirements would each serve well? And which of these do you think would be better for a high-load, high-speed scenario?

Comment: In general, it is wise to have lots of 'identical' tables.  It is a maintenance problem, etc.

Comment: @RickJames I assume there's a typo in your comment and you meant "it is NOT wise".

Comment: I would keep non-paritioned tables. I would not partition the data this way unless there's a very compelling reason to do so. Performing a partitioning like this can become nightmare. It's quite error prone and expensive to code and to debug.

Comment: TL/TR: keep your current design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are suggesting is essentially [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html), so I suggest reading the docs about that. It's mainly advantageous when your operations each cover most of one partition (i.e. select all data for one user, or delete all data for one user).

Most use cases, however, are better served by having one properly indexed table. It's a much simpler structure, and can be very performant. If all of your queries are for a single user, then you'll want all of the indexes to start with the `userId` column, and postgres will use them to efficiently reach only the relevant rows. And if a day comes when you want to query data across multiple users, it will be much easier to do that.

I advise you not to take my word for it, though. Create both structures, generate fake data to fill them up, and see how they behave!

Comment: Right. Partitioning won't speed up index scans, only sequential scans restricted to a few partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

- You might end up with x amount of tables if you have one per user. How many "users" do you expect?
- The `json` data is unbound and might grow as your solution/app grows. How will you handle missing keys/values?
- The `Users` table will grow horizontally (more columns) where you should always aim to grow vertically (more rows)

A better solution would be to hold your data in tables related to the user_id.
ie. a "keys" table which holds the key, date_added, active and foreign key (user_id)

This will also solve saving your data as a `json` which, in you example, will be difficult to maintain. Rather open that json up into a table where you can benefit from indexes and clustering.

---

If you reference your `user_id` in separate tables as a foreign key, you can partition or cluster these tables on that key to significantly increase speed and compensate for growth. Which means you have a single table for `users` (id, name, active, created_at, ...) and lots of tables linked to that user, eg.
`subscriptions` (id, user_id, ...), `items` (id, user_id, ...), `things` (id,user_id, ...)